# Queries broken after migration to Hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

When updating to Hibernate 6 (coming from 5.6) some of the existing queries gets broken.

For example, executing this query works fine in 5.6:

```
  @Query(
      "SELECT new Position(p, CASE WHEN p.sourceSetId IS NULL THEN p.sourceSetName ELSE s.name END as sourceSetName, pos.optimizedDisplayOrder) FROM Position p "
          + "LEFT JOIN Position pos ON pos.projectId = p.projectId AND pos.positionId = p.sourceSetPositionId "
          + "LEFT JOIN Manufacturer m ON p.optimizedItem.manufacturer.manufacturerId = m.manufacturerId "
          + "LEFT JOIN Set s ON p.sourceSetId = s.setId AND p.projectId = s.projectId "
          + "WHERE p.setId = :setId AND p.projectId = :projectId "
          + "AND (UPPER(p.optimizedItem.code) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')) "
          + "OR UPPER(m.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')) "
          + "OR UPPER(p.optimizedItem.description) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')))")
```

but leads to the following error in 6:

```
2023-05-16T16:35:37.867+02:00  WARN 21803 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2023-05-16T16:35:37.867+02:00 ERROR 21803 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "o1_0"
  Position: 743
2023-05-16T16:35:37.875+02:00 ERROR 21803 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.position_id,p1_0.comment,p1_0.create_date,p1_0.last_modified_by,p1_0.last_modified_date,p1_0.optimized_display_order,case when p1_0.optimized_item_id IS NULL then p1_0.original_item_id else p1_0.optimized_item_id end ,p1_0.optimized_item_id,p1_0.optimized_quantity,p1_0.original_display_order,p1_0.original_item_id,p1_0.original_quantity,p1_0.project_id,p1_0.set_id,p1_0.source_set_id,p1_0.source_set_name,p1_0.source_set_position_id,case when p1_0.source_set_id is null then p1_0.source_set_name else s1_0.name end,p2_0.optimized_display_order from nemo_dev.position p1_0 left join nemo_dev.position p2_0 on p2_0.project_id=p1_0.project_id and p2_0.position_id=p1_0.source_set_position_id left join nemo_dev.manufacturer m1_0 on o1_0.manufacturer_id=m1_0.manufacturer_id left join nemo_dev.set s1_0 on p1_0.source_set_id=s1_0.set_id and p1_0.project_id=s1_0.project_id join nemo_dev.item o1_0 on o1_0.item_id=case when p1_0.optimized_item_id IS NULL then p1_0.original_item_id else p1_0.optimized_item_id end  where p1_0.set_id=? and p1_0.project_id=? and (upper(o1_0.code) like upper(('%'||?||'%')) escape '' or upper(m1_0.name) like upper(('%'||?||'%')) escape '' or upper(o1_0.description) like upper(('%'||?||'%')) escape '') order by p1_0.optimized_display_order asc offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "o1_0"
  Position: 743
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar:42.5.4]
```

I have read the [migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc) but couldn't find an explanation for this.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Certainly looks like a bug from here, but _please_ simplify this down to a **minimal** reproducer before reporting it.

Comment: One thing to mention: When i change the order of the LEFT JOIN clauses (first the manufacterer and the the positions), the error disappears.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from the query your are returning the DTO having the same name as the entity you are querying from. So you need to distinguish between them somehow. Please use fully-qualified name for DTO declaration:

```java
@Query(
      "SELECT new com.your.package.name.Position(p, CASE WHEN p.sourceSetId IS NULL THEN p.sourceSetName ELSE s.name END as sourceSetName, pos.optimizedDisplayOrder) FROM Position p "
          + "LEFT JOIN Position pos ON pos.projectId = p.projectId AND pos.positionId = p.sourceSetPositionId "
          + "LEFT JOIN Manufacturer m ON p.optimizedItem.manufacturer.manufacturerId = m.manufacturerId "
          + "LEFT JOIN Set s ON p.sourceSetId = s.setId AND p.projectId = s.projectId "
          + "WHERE p.setId = :setId AND p.projectId = :projectId "
          + "AND (UPPER(p.optimizedItem.code) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')) "
          + "OR UPPER(m.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')) "
          + "OR UPPER(p.optimizedItem.description) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :searchParam, '%')))")
```

Comment: I am returning the entity itself. Tried it with using the FQN, but this didn't change anything.